# What is this bug?

Tags: bugs

The bug is about the size of a ladybug its black with gold spots and legs? It also seem to have wings and seem to have a smell that's quite nauseating
[image]
[image]

Comment: What part of the world? Europe? Africa? Antarctica?

Comment: South east asia

Comment: Hard to say - could be [Nezara viridula instar?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nezara_viridula#/media/File:Pentatomidae_-_Nezara_viridula-003.JPG)

Comment: I don’t know if I can advertise another site but Reddit has an entire subreddit dedicated to bug identification.